Code in mnielson book on neural networks not working
I am learning neural networks from the book http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap1.html
and I have created the code, making sure to use the up to date version for python 3.10 from github, and I am encountering an error when I try to run this bit of code in python shell: .
The error is as follows:

does anyone know why this is, or how to fix it? I am running this in pycharm in python 3.10

Have you kept the directory structure from GitHub? mnist_loader.py expects that it's inside a directory (src, but that name doesn't matter), and next to that directory there's a data, containing mnist.pkl.gz. You either have to reproduce this structure, or edit the code to look for the data file where it actually is.

ohhh this is what I forgot to do, thank you for the help

It looks like the issue is related to copy pasting the commands from the book into the python shell. The easiest way would be to run it if you bring the second line into one line:
So from:
training_data, validation_data, test_data = \
... mnist_loader.load_data_wrapper()

To this:
training_data, validation_data, test_data = mnist_loader.load_data_wrapper()

Give it a try!
EDIT: The other way should be to remove the extra three dots you have in the shell there, when the line is broken using \
EDIT2: For the FileNotFound exception, paste the file called mnist.pkl.gz into a data/ directory two levels up your working directory. Your folder structure needs to match what you see in the github repo to be able to run it.

Thank you, this fixed it, - I am now encountering a different error when importing them - I have edited the question to include this, do you know why this other issue is occurring? - the code comes from here https://github.com/unexploredtest/neural-networks-and-deep-learning/blob/master/src/mnist_loader.py

Are you able to import mnist_loader successfully or does that show errors too?
Have you grabbed the data that the code is trying to use and pasted it somewhere in your environment? Check EDIT2.
